# What sports / hobbies would strengthen the lower traps?

Tags: shoulders, posture, sports, trapezius

I've had a number of physio appointments for my winging scapular, and have mostly been given exercises for my lower traps and serratus anterior. I've now been told I'm okay to self-manage.

The exercises she's given me do seem pretty effective (at least in resolving the pain I was getting) but I think I'm a long way off my scapular being in the correct position.

I plan to continue with the rehab exercises, but also looking to find a hobby that would help strengthen my lower traps even further.

I've thought about all sorts of different hobbies I could take up (not involving the gym) — bouldering, cycling, swimming etc — but it seems like *everything* is biased towards internal rotation / rounded shoulders etc.

Only thing I can think of is rowing, but that's not very feasible.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

**Edit:** I've just looked into swimming a little more, and think breaststroke swimming might be a good idea?

Comment: I have found that the best way to work the lower traps is by pull downs with a really wide grip focusing on pulling the shoulderblades down at the start of the movement. Is that what your physio told you to do? One point I think is a problem is that physios often prescribe exercises that do not require much equipment but instead elastic bands. However these exercises do not scale very well. They can only take you from weak to not so weak. A cable pulldown machine on the other hand can bring your lower traps from weak to extremely strong.

Comment: @Andy thank you — I'm planning on getting back into the gym when they re-open – hadn't thought about using a wide-grip but will give it a try! Ideally I'd like to find some form of hobby that will help too though

Comment: Yes covid sucks. I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3wluQOeu3U useful for understanding how the traps works. 
I would also think that breaststroke swimming would be good.